# How do I see what git creds are stored in osxkeychain

Tags: macos, mac, git, keychain, credentials-manager

Looking at my git config it seems im using: `credential.helper=osxkeychain`

Set it up a while back and I dont remember what creds are in there.

How do I view the creds git is using in credential.helper=osxkeychain?

Answer (score 5):

This article [Updating Credentials from the OSX Keychain](https://help.github.com/articles/updating-credentials-from-the-osx-keychain/) provides detail on how to access the Keychain and see the credentials related to Git.

A summary from the article is:

1. Spotlight Search barIn Finder, search for the Keychain Access app.
2. In Keychain Access, search for github.com.
3. GitHub Password Entry in KeychainFind the "internet password" entry for github.com.
4. Edit or delete the entry accordingly.